# Python - groupby sum map to another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, pandas-groupby, series

My dataframe A:

```
id   groupA    groupB    groupC    groupD   groupE    ...
001    0         0         0         0        0
002    0         0         0         0        0
003    0         0         0         0        0
  ...
```

Dataframe B:

```
id     value     count
001    groupA      2
002    groupB      1
001    groupB      3
001    groupC      1
003    groupC      2
002    groupA      1


dfB.groupby(['id', 'value'])['count'].sum()
```

By running this groupby I get:

```
id  value 
1   groupA    2
    groupB    3
    groupC    1
2   groupA    1
    groupB    1
3   groupC    2
Name: count, dtype: int64
```

I was trying to transform this result to a dataframe and map it back to dataframe A, but it didn't work out.

My ideal dataframe Aoutput is:

```
id   groupA    groupB    groupC    groupD   groupE    ...
001    2         3         1         0        0
002    1         1         0         0        0
003    0         0         2         0        0
  ...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pivot the df2 and merge the two dataframes,

```
df2.pivot_table(index = 'id', columns = 'value', values = 'count', aggfunc='sum').reset_index()\
.merge(df1, how = 'left').fillna(0).astype(int)


    id  groupA  groupB  groupC  groupD  groupE
0   1   2       3       1       0       0
1   2   1       1       0       0       0
2   3   0       0       2       0       0
```

You can do the same with groupby as well,

```
df2.groupby(['id', 'value'])['count'].sum().unstack().reset_index()\
.merge(df1, how = 'left').fillna(0).astype(int)
```

Comment: Nice one , but do not forget the columns should using left join with df1 as well . :-)

Answer (score 3):

Do with one-line chain with `reindex`

```
dfb.groupby(['id', 'value'])['count'].sum().\
     unstack(fill_value=0).\
       reindex(columns=dfa.columns,index=dfa.id,fill_value=0).\
        drop('id',1)
    groupA  groupB  groupC  groupD  groupE
id                                        
1        2       3       1       0       0
2        1       1       0       0       0
3        0       0       2       0       0
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [pivot](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html) like this too. Seems cleaner

```
df

   id    value  count
0   1   groupA  2
1   2   groupB  1
2   1   groupB  3
3   1   groupC  1
4   3   groupC  2
5   2   groupA  1
6   3   groupA  5

aa = pd.DataFrame(df.groupby(by=["id", "value"]).sum()).reset_index().pivot(index="id", columns="value", values="count").fillna(0)
aa.columns.name = aa.index.name
aa.index.name = ""
aa

id  groupA  groupB  groupC
1   5.0 3.0 1.0
2   1.0 1.0 0.0
3   5.0 0.0 2.0
```

Comment: The OP used groupby with sum to convert the original data, which means that there are duplicated entries and pivot clearly won't work in that case

Comment: My bad. Updated my answer. Thanks